# spring mvc Hibernate Search query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working with spring, using hibernate, maven and mysql, i'm trying to make a simple site for movies and actors. What i'd like is a search method, where you type a word, or part of a word/name and you will get some results, this is my query:

```
@Transactional
public List<Movie> searchForMovie(String searchText) {
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getSession());

    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Movie.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword().onFields("year", "title").matching(searchText)
            .createQuery();

    org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Movie.class);

    List<Movie> results = hibQuery.list();
    return results;
}
```

As you can see, I am using 'keyword', this means you would have to search for the whole word/name, not only part of it.  For example, if I want to find the movie 'hunger games' I would have to type 'hunger' or 'games', what I want is it to be possible to only write 'hunge' and still get results. I cant seem to find a query that will do this, thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use hibernate wildcard queries for this.

```
? - represents a single character
* - represents any character sequence.
```

Please also note that for performance purposes, it is recommended that query do not start with ? or either *.

```
   QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Movie.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
                .keyword().wildcard().onFields("year", "title")
                .matching(searchText + "*")
                .createQuery();
```

See hibernate docs for complete reference.
5.1.2.3 Wildcard Queries.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#search-query-querydsl

Comment: thank you guys, this works perfectly! (I did try with wildcard before, but didn't use the '*' ..) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just change your .matching line to the following:

```
.matching("*"+searchText+"*")
```

Use wildcards to get your results in any combination you deem fit.

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fuzzySearch of Hibernate Search on keyword. Your code will be like this :

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
           .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Movie.class).get();

         org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
           .keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("year","title")
           .matching(searchText)
           .createQuery();
```

See hibernate docs for complete reference.

5.1.2.2 Fuzzy Queries.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#search-query-querydsl